# Change DataLabels of Excel chart at once in C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts, fonts, format

I'm using the following code to change the datalabels of excel chart in C#

```
using Xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using officeState = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState;
....


for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
{
    series1 = (Xl.Series)xlChart.SeriesCollection(i + 1);
    for (int k = 0; k < cols.Count; k++)
    {
        Xl.DataLabel dl = series1.DataLabels(k + 1) as Xl.DataLabel;
        dl.Font.Bold = officeState.msoTrue;
        dl.Font.Size = 11;
        dl.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
    }

}
```

Is it possible to change all datalabel font at once ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to bold the data labels in a series. I've tested this with both bar charts and pie charts and it works well.

```
var series = chartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection() as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.SeriesCollection;
foreach (var ser in series)
{
    var DataLabels = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series)ser).DataLabels();
    DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
}
```